# Show that posterior distribution is proportional to likelihood times prior when both y and X are in the equation

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior

Reviewing MCMC for my work, I have got a problem with the very fundamental equation for the posterior:

$$
P(\theta |y, X) = \frac{P(y|X, \theta)P(\theta)}{p(y|X)} = \frac{P(y|X, \theta)P(\theta)}{Z} 
$$

I found the equation above in this [lecture note](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Egarnett/cse515t/fall_2019/files/lecture_notes/8.pdf) (first equation on page 3) and also in this [lecture note](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Enando/540-2013/lectures/l14.pdf) (page 3). As well-known, the equation simply says the posterior is a product of the likelihood and the prior divided by a normalization constant.

As I try to derive the equivalence, however, I have reached a different end:
$$
P(\theta |y, X) = \frac{P(y, X, \theta)}{p(y, X)} = \frac{P(y, X, \theta)}{P(X, \theta)}\frac{P(X, \theta)}{P(X)}\frac{P(X)}{P(y, X)} = \frac{P(y|X, \theta)P(\theta|X)}{p(y|X)}
$$
Here, instead of the prior P(theta), I have P(theta|X) which is not the same as the prior unless theta is independent of X.

How do I prove that the posterior is proportional to likelihood times prior in this setting? I will appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: The assumption is that $p(\theta|X)=p(\theta)$, i.e. that the prior on $\theta$ does not depend on $X$.

Comment: Thanks, Xi'an! Your answer means it is just an assumption made for a conceptual purpose, right? Lots of thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is a further assumption.